# How to set a download counter on Hyperlink Control inside Repeater? asp.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, hyperlink, repeater, asprepeater

I have a hyperlink inside a repeater control for the list of pdf. I want to set a download counter on each click on each hyperlink. The FileName must be a parameter. My code is basically like below. There is also code that calls stored procedure and bind it to the repeater on page_load.

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptPDF" runat="server">
<ItemTemplate>
<div class="repeaterResources">
<b><%# Eval("Name") %></b><br />
    <b>Description</b> <%# Eval("Description") %><br />
    <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink2" runat="server" class="downloadLink" NavigateUrl='<%# "~/PDF/" & Eval("Filename") %>' Target="_blank">Download</asp:HyperLink><br /><br />                
</div>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

The mystery bit is how to get a button click event from here. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the OnCommand event and set the CommandArgument attribute with a value using

`<%# Eval('myvalue') %>`.

MSDN has an example minus the repeater: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.oncommand.aspx

Sample:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="repeater" runat="server">
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="button1" OnCommand="button1_command" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("myvalue") %>' />
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Comment: It's also worth mentioning that on your code-behind, CommandArgument is an object, so I usually call .ToString() on it just to make sure I'm working with a string and asp .net hasn't done anything crazy with the types.

Comment: Thanks Steve, but this won't open a new tab rite?

Comment: Right, the OnCommand event handler is handled during the postback, so no new tabs. If you want to open a new tab with a link, use `target="_blank"` on your hyperlink (but not your postback one because you can't post back to a new tab!)